# Xsl include and SonarQube / XXE attacks vulnerability alert

Tags: java, xslt, sonarqube

I'm working on an old Java J2EE Jdk 8 web app with XSL transformations to produce html.
Our xsl files sometimes include other xsl files (for factorization purposes).

**Example**
th1.xsl file

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">  
<!-- TEMPLATE TH1 -->
...
<xsl:include href="disclaimer.xsl"/>
...
```

Java part

```java
String xslt = "th1.xsl";
String xml = "xxe.xml";
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml), new StreamResult(writer));
String result = writer.toString();
```

**Problem**
Recently, we plug SonarQube on it.
We have a vulnerability alert from SonarQube: "Disable access to external entities in XML parsing."
And, according to SonarQube, we shall disable access to external Xsl by using these lines:

```
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

But, by doing so, we cannot anymore use the "xsl:include" tag because of this exception:

```
Caused By: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: file:///conf/myWebApp/xsl/modele/th1.xsl: line 6: Could not read stylesheet target 'disclaimer.xsl', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalStylesheet property.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:761)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicTransformerFactory.newTransformer(WebLogicTransformerFactory.java:208)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.newTransformer(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:209)
```

**Solution Tried**

```
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "file");
```

This solution prevents the exception to be thrown but SonarQube raised the same vulnerability alert.

I understand the need to prevent the xsl include tag to access anything.
So, I'm looking for a way to restrict xsl include to access only a trusted folder (containing my xsl files), something that will be SonarQube friendly.

**UPDATE**
As said below, I managed to take into account the sonarQube note. The only thing needed to make it work is to write an URI resolver.

```java
URIResolver uRIResolver = new URIResolver() {
    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {

    // Example: href = "disclaimer.xsl"
    // Example: base = "file:///appli/myAppli/xsl/th1.xsl"
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(href);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new TransformerException("Unable to resolve " + href + " from classpath");
        }
        return new StreamSource(inputStream);
    }
};

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tFactory.setURIResolver(uRIResolver);
tFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
tFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a URIResolver and set it on the TransformerFactory to check that the URI references in xsl:include only access safe locations.

I don't know if this will prevent the security warnings (which are probably not very smart) but it should remove any security risks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I wrote an URIResolver which is a good thing from a security point of view.  However, the sonarQube's alert is still here.

Comment: Well, you have to decide whether your objective is to make the system secure or to eliminate all security warnings. You can achieve either of these objectives without achieving the other.

Comment: I made a mistake.
Writing an URI resolver AND taking into account sonarQube alert made it all works.
So, thank you for your answer.